# Highlight a day on the calendar

Tags: calendar

I want to mark days that are important to me on the calendar, such as birthdays, full moons. Is it possible to make it a different color, highlight it in a circle or draw a moon icon?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmap} % поиск в PDF
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} % кодировка
%\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} % Отступы
% Folding + calendar example from the PGF manual.
%
% Author: Till Tantau
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,folding}
\begin{document}
    \sffamily\scriptsize
    \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,
        every calendar/.style={
            at={(-8ex,4ex)},
            week list,
            month label above centered, 
            month text=\bfseries\textcolor{red}{\%mt} \%y0,
            if={(Sunday, Saturday) [black!50]}
        }]
    \tikzfoldingdodecahedron[
        folding line length=2.5cm,
        face 1={ \calendar [month text=\textcolor{red}{Январь}  \textbf{\the\year}, 
 dates=\the\year-01-01 to \the\year-01-last];},
        face 2={ \calendar [month text=\textcolor{red}{Февраль} \textbf{\the\year},
dates=\the\year-02-01 to \the\year-02-last];},
        face 3={ \calendar [month text=\textcolor{red}{Март} \textbf{\the\year}, 
dates=\the\year-03-01 to \the\year-03-last];},
        face 4={ \calendar [month text=\textcolor{red}{Апрель}  \textbf{\the\year}, 
dates=\the\year-04-01 to \the\year-04-last];},
        face 5={ \calendar [month text=\textcolor{red}{Май}  \textbf{\the\year},
dates=\the\year-05-01 to \the\year-05-last];},
        face 6={ \calendar [month text=\textcolor{red}{Июнь}  \textbf{\the\year},
dates=\the\year-06-01 to \the\year-06-last];},
        face 7={ \calendar [month text=\textcolor{red}{Июль}  \textbf{\the\year},
dates=\the\year-07-01 to \the\year-07-last];},
        face 8={ \calendar [month text=\textcolor{red}{Август}  \textbf{\the\year},
dates=\the\year-08-01 to \the\year-08-last];},
        face 9={ \calendar [month text=\textcolor{red}{Сентябрь}  \textbf{\the\year},
dates=\the\year-09-01 to \the\year-09-last];},
        face 10={\calendar [month text=\textcolor{red}{Октябрь}  \textbf{\the\year},
dates=\the\year-10-01 to \the\year-10-last];},
        face 11={\calendar [month text=\textcolor{red}{Ноябрь}  \textbf{\the\year},
dates=\the\year-11-01 to \the\year-11-last];},
        face 12={\calendar [month text=\textcolor{red}{Декабрь}  \textbf{\the\year},
dates=\the\year-12-01 to \the\year-12-last];}
    ];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `if (equals=yyyy-mm-dd)` syntax as described in the [TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) on page 589. This can be added to the monthly calendar specifications.

Example for december, showing a text color, circle, and an image:

```
face 12={\calendar [month text=\textcolor{red}{Декабрь}  \textbf{\the\year},
dates=\the\year-12-01 to \the\year-12-last]
          if (equals=2022-12-14) [blue]
          if (equals=2022-12-19) {\draw[xshift=-6.5pt,yshift=2pt] (0,0) circle (5pt);}
          if (equals=2022-12-07) {\node[xshift=-4pt,yshift=4pt]{\includegraphics[width=20pt]{moon}};}
          ;}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that `xshift` and `yshift` are used manually to position the circle and the image. The TikZ manual also provides a more automatic way by repositioning the calendar itself, however the shifts will be the same for most dates so this is not very difficult I think.

---

To replace the day number by an image (instead of an overlay) you can set the `day code` for a specific date:

```
if (equals=2022-12-07) [day code={\node[xshift=-4pt,yshift=4pt]{\includegraphics[width=20pt]{moon}};}]
```

Comment: Thank you, you answered my question, but I would like to ask one more thing: This method allows you to overlay an image on a number, while the number remains visible. Is it possible to replace the number with an image?

Comment: @Антон see edit.